# CSS width:fit-content not working on iphones

Tags: html, css, iphone, safari

I have a css class with the element's width set to fit-content. The CSS works fine on every device except for iPhones. Anyone knows any fix??

```
.sidenav {
    width: fit-content;
    z-index: 100;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Please give us more clue about the proble, what do you want, and what actually get for example

Comment: make the element inline-block or table instead

Answer (score 0):

Support of `width: fit-content` is not great.
https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_properties_width_fit-content

You can instead use `display: table` and `margin: auto` to center elements.

Comment: caniuse says it's been available on iOS Safari since 2017, however it's also not working for me in 2022